# Rails: Useful example of delegate and Law of Demeter

Tags: design, object-oriented, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning about `delegate` and the Law of Demeter. I understand the Law of Demeter, but I can't seem to find a good example of where using `delegate` to avoid breaking the law would actually even be useful.

I want to find an example related to my project, since I have to give a presentation. The only line of code that I found that could possibly be breaking the Law of Demeter is the following:

`@game.promotions.find_by_promo_type("cross")`

The model `Game` `has_many` `Promotions` and it is reaching across another model to execute a `find` call based on promotions attribute `promo_type`. From my understanding this is a violation of the Law of Demeter, and I should implement the following solution.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :promotions

   delegate :find_by_promo_type, :to => :promotion
end
```

Can you give me an example where this would actually be useful besides "the Law of Demeter says so".

The only thing I can think of, is for some reason I wanted to change the name of `promotions` to `promos`, then the solution would be useful because I would only need to make the following change and `:find_by_promo_type` will still work for `Game`

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :promos

   delegate :find_by_promo_type, :to => :promos
end
```

The only thing is, I believe this argument is flawed. If I were to change a models name, I would also have to refactor code in many other places that don't even break the Law of Demeter. It's hard to believe that this is all the Law of Demeter can accomplish in regards to this example.

Can somebody please help me understand this.

Comment: According to the book im reading 'Rails Antipatterns', breaking the law of demeter is when I am trying to directly access a method/attribute of a model that does not belong to me. Example: I am trying to access `find_by_promo_type` from the `Game` model through `promotions`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, for example, you wanted to cache or log that promotion, only when you access it through Game. Having broken the Law of Demeter, you cannot do this easily. You have to find every reference to `.promotions.find_by_promo_type` and identify the ones that are applied to Games and change them to `.find_promotion_by_promo_type` before you can add that code.

If you've delegated it in your code then you simply replace that with a full-blown method (and then rename it, if necessary).

That said, the Law of Demeter should really be called the Guideline of Demeter. It's a very good principle to bear in mind but, as you identified, it can add maintenance to common updates, to avoid a major problem if you make a change that you are 99% sure you'll never make.